# NativeModules not included in React native

Tags: react-native

I've created a file (see below) but when I try to use it in React Native, the module is null. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

```
#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"
@interface CalendarManager : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>
@end

-----------------------

#import "CalendarManager.h"

@implementation CalendarManager

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(addEvent:(NSString *)name location:(NSString *)location)
{
}
@end
```

Then in React, I do this:

```
import React, { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
var CalendarManager = NativeModules.CalendarManager;
console.log(NativeModules); // This is null
```

Comment: Was it added to the app project on Xcode?

Comment: @JeanRegisser I believe so, I added them as regular files in xcode. File->New

Comment: And does them actually belong to the app target?

Comment: Yes sir, they are added to the root target.

Comment: This helped me: https://github.com/weflex/react-native-wechat/issues/33

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to check the console logs in normal regular terminal, then it will display like this, but i would suggest you to debug it with chrome debugger and hopefully you can see your NativeModules object present there with all properties.